# Use HMAC-SHA-256 or HMAC-SHA-512 with the Google Authenticator App

Tags: sha, multi-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

The [Google Authenticator](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki) implements the one-time passcode as described in [RFC 4226](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4226), HOTP: An HMAC-Based One-Time Password Algorithm and its extension [RFC 6238](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238), TOTP: Time-Based One-Time Password Algorithm.

RFC 6238 specifies the algoritm;

```
HOTP(K,T) = Truncate(HASH-FUNCTION(K,T))
```

Where K is the shared secret and T the current Unix time (i.e., the number of seconds elapsed since midnight UTC of January 1, 1970). As for HASH-FUNCTION RFC 6238 describes;

[image: TOTP implementations MAY use HMAC-SHA-256 or HMAC-SHA-512 functions, based on SHA-256 or SHA-512 [SHA2] hash functions, instead of the HMAC-SHA-1 function that has been specified for the HOTP computation in [RFC4226].]

And indeed, i saw several server side implementations with these different HASH-FUNCTIONs.
But what about the Google Authenticator App itself? The App defaults with HMAC-SHA-1 (i know this from tests), but can i configure the App towards HMAC-SHA-256 or HMAC-SHA-512? How?

Comment: Not according to https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format#algorithm

Comment: Strange, i did some tests and it seems to work with both SHA-256 or SHA-512 and the QR code option ... Maybe the code is updated and the wiki isn't ...